# What is correct way to check if rune is in Basic Multilingual Plane?

Tags: go, unicode

I want to check, whether a given rune is in a [basic multilingual plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) or not.

That is, what to put in this function - https://play.golang.org/p/3szTn8pP7xe

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func isBMP(r rune) bool {
    // ???
    return false
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(isBMP(rune('պ'))) // expect true
    fmt.Println(isBMP(rune(''))) // expect false
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic Multilingual Plane have the following code point ranges allocated:

```
0000–​0FFF    8000–​8FFF
1000–​1FFF    9000–​9FFF
2000–​2FFF    A000–​AFFF
3000–​3FFF    B000–​BFFF
4000–​4FFF    C000–​CFFF
5000–​5FFF    D000–​DFFF
6000–​6FFF    E000–​EFFF
7000–​7FFF    F000–​FFFF
```

So to tell if a rune falls in the basic multilingual plane, just check if it falls inside any of these ranges. Since these ranges cover all values between `0` and `0xffff` (both inclusive), just check it like this:

```
func isBMP(r rune) bool {
    return r >= 0 && r <= 0xffff
}
```

Note that since `rune` is alias for `int32`, it may have negative values, so also checking if it's not negative is important.

This will output your expected result. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zAfey8cQZrQ).

Note #2: iterating over the runes of a string which contains invalid UTF-8 bytes, you will get the Unicode replacement character for the invalid bytes, which is `0xfffd`. If you want to exclude those from your test, you could modify it like:

```
func isBMP(r rune) bool {
    return r >= 0 && r <= 0xffff && r != 0xfffd
}
```

Comment: I copy-pasted a wrong letter, sorry. I will edit the question.

Comment: Note: for non-trivial ranges there is also [`unicode.RangeTable`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode#RangeTable) which can be used with things like [`unicode.In`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#In). The [`golang.org/x/text/unicode/rangetable`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/unicode/rangetable) package provides some utilities for creating and inspecting `unicode.RangeTables`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with go. However a bit of Googleing suggests that a rune is in fact an int32 so as anything in the basic multilingual plain has a code point between 0 and 65535 you should be able to do this

```
func isBMP(r rune) bool {
    if r <= 65535 {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```